# AWS LAMBDA, PUPPETEER, page.goto() ERROR CONNECTION TIMED OUT

Tags: lambda, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer-lambda
I managed to get getBrowser() working, but when it comes to 
await page.goto(url) it stops and I have timeout error.
This is my code:

```
case "connect":
  console.log('case connect');
  await page.goto(actions.url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded']});
  page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
  console.log('page go to url');
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  console.log('case connect passed');
break;
```

Does anyone has idea what might help?
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of  'actions.url' ?

Comment: https://shop.halebop.se/mobilabonnemang ....I also trie with https://www.google.com but same thing.
I am printing the url to the console, which means that I have internet connection on Lambda coz I get the url from online db.

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the timeout? Something like `await page.goto(actions.url, {timeout: 5000, waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded']});`

See [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1004)

Comment: did you solved? If yes please write the solution

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this issue can be resolved by **increasing your Lambda memory**. Memory is most important since it also give more computing power.

Increasing timeout also help but is not useful as memory.